# How to use URLEncoder with UTF-8

Tags: java, android

Documentation says I should use UTF-8 with [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

I tried UTF-8. I got "cannot resolve symbol" error

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF_8");
```

I also tried this, but the API level is higher than I want it (level 19).

```
String UTF_8 = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString();
```

What is the proper and simple way to use this method with UTF-8?

Comment: "cannot resolve symbol" sounds like a compiler error, do you have more information in the error trace ?

Comment: Huh, it actually worked. So why am I getting the "cannot resolve symbol" error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way is to spell it right. Try `URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");` not with an underscore.

Comment: I'm surprised/disappointed Java hasn't declared a `final const` for this!

Comment: @W.K.S use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()` instead of hardcoding a String.

Answer (score 2):

**URLEncoder**

> This class is used to encode a string using the format required by
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME content type.
>
> All characters except letters ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z') and numbers
>   ('0'..'9') and characters '.', '-', '*', '_' are converted into their
>   hexadecimal value prepended by '%'. For example: '#' -> %23. In
>   addition, spaces are substituted by '+'.

The recommended encoding scheme to use is **`UTF-8`** .

Use

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```